# How configure an Eclipse PDE Build (executed from Ant) to fetch plugins/features from an Eclipse Official repo?

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-juno, eclipse-pde

I want to generate an Eclipse RCP product from my Gradle build pipeline.
I came up with this command to generate the product:

```
java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar \
     -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner \
     -buildfile   plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_*/scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml \ 
     -Dbuilder=$productDir
```

It is failing not finding a plugin.

```
v20121114-140810/scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml:69:
Unable to find plug-in: org.eclipse.birt.jetty.overlay_0.0.0
```

Same thing happens for other plugins like PyDev, Gef and platform dependent fragments (found in the DeltaPack).

How do I have to configure the `build.properties` or the Ant XML files to instruct Eclipse to fetch any missing plugin/feature from the `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/201303010900` repository?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the online-fetch of plugins.

But you can install Eclipse RCP Delta-pack and it comes with all the platform-dependent fragments, that your PDE build is missing.

Once you copied it to your install, edit your Target Platform in Eclipse preferences to include the new Fragments and Plugins too. Then add all those dependencies to your Product.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you suggested at the moment I manually downloaded the DeltaPack and all plugins I need. What I need is skipping this manual process and let eclipse automatically fetch any missing plugin from an online repo.

Comment: Please up vote the question if you find it useful to give it more visibility helping finding an answer.

Comment: So; you want to install/update plugins automatically in fact. You can achieve this trough Provisioning Platform (p2). I'm not sure you can do this without an Eclipse with it's UI running, because some of these plugins have EULAs, READ-ME which you need to accept before installing. Fragments are even more likely to not be EPL-conform.